# asynchronous vs synchronous training

Tags: deep-learning, train

As I understood that the difference is asynchronous vs synchronous is the following: 
"When a neural network is viewed as a collection of connected computation devices, the question arises whether the nodes/devices share a common clock, so that they all perform their computations ("fire") at the same time, (i.e. **synchronously**) or whether they fire at different times, e.g. they may fire equally often on average, but in a random sequence (i.e. **asynchronously**). 
{from: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/mldict.html}

but I don't understand where to use each of these type. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is another meaning of asynchronous that I think is more likely the definition you are looking for. It can also mean that during training you have multiple workers that are running in parallel and all making updates to the model parameters. These updates can be done synchronously, where the gradients from the workers are aggregated and then applied all at once, or asynchronously where the workers apply the gradients without waiting for the others.